# css background-size property wont work for iphone?

Tags: css, iphone, background-image

I have this code:

```
background: url("../images/step1.gif") no-repeat top right/contain content-box;
```

but it wont work on iphone (I have iOS 4.3, I dont know about later versions) since no background is displayed at all. Do I need to change the syntax or is it just that the background-size property is not possible at all?

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't it work at all, or from specific pages?

Comment: For all but i already solved it. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

I was requested to post the solution. Okay, its very simple. I just took the value for background-size off the shorthand background property and stated it as a separate property like this:

```
background: url("../images/step1.gif") no-repeat top right content-box;background-size:contain;-webkit-background-size:contain;
```

That did it for me. You have to write more code but well, its the way things work for now.